# Open source project developed using TDD and Java

Tags: java, open-source, tdd

I'm looking for a project that:

1) Has avaiable sources including tests.

2) Was/is developed strictly using *TDD*.

3) Is written in *Java* and JUnit.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is TDD, by the way?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573699/open-source-projects-that-demonstrate-tdd-and-solid-priciples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) comes to mind.

According to Erich Gamma in [this interview](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/gammadpP.html), it was developed "in strict test-driven way." I've also heard interviews with both Gamma and Beck that repeated this statement.

Answer (score 5):

We wrote [JBehave](http://jbehave.org), the BDD scenario framework, using BDD at a unit level too. Very slightly different to TDD but provides many of the same values. (You'll find the tests at src/behaviour rather than src/test).

Ditto with [Tyburn](http://code.google.com/p/tyburn/), a little Swing automation harness I wrote some time ago.

You might also look at [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

I recommend these three because they've been written to support aspects of BDD itself, so the people who wrote them really, really care about this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) and [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) are good open source examples that are heavily unit-tested.

EDIT, any of the apache commons projects as well...

Answer (score 0):

["Good example of complex code using TDD"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/21791/602) is a question on the Programmers SE site with answers that could be of interest to you.